# Search and filter through array javascript

Tags: javascript

Excuse the title I'm not sure how to describe what I'm doing

I have a textarea where people can write comments but they can also mention people using an @mention system I have made... now my only issue is once the user starts typing after the @ it doesnt narrow down the users so say I have an array of objects like so..

```
users = [
  {
    name: steve,
    id: 47 
  },
  {
    name: james,
    id: 41
  },
  {
    name: guy,
    id: 44 
  },
  {
    name: troy,
    id: 32 
  }
]
```

how can I filter out users in the array depending on the string thats being written after an `@` symbol so If I write @tr in my text area my users array should now look like this

```
users = [
  {
    name: troy,
    id: 32
  }
]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `filter` to check for if the `name` of the user being iterated over `includes` the substring in question:

```js
const users = [
  {
    name: 'steve',
    id: 47 
  },
  {
    name: 'james',
    id: 41
  },
  {
    name: 'guy',
    id: 44 
  },
  {
    name: 'troy',
    id: 32 
  }
];

const substr = 'tr';
console.log(
  users.filter(({ name }) => name.includes(substr))
);
```

Also make sure your `name` values are *strings*.

Comment: Sorry just another quick question how can I only check for the string after the `@`??

Comment: @SmokeyDawson If the input string actually has the `@` in it, then match everything that comes after the `@`: `value.match(/@(.+$)/)[1]` or if there might be multiple `@`s, `/@([^@]+$)/`

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend an approach similar to the other answer, but I would use startsWith instead of includes and make sure to lowercase both strings when comparing them. This will give you more accurate results.

```js
const names = [{ name: 'Bob'}, { name: 'Sally' }, { name: 'Frank' }, { name: 'Lester' }, { name: 'Bo' }, { name: 'Salazar' }, { name: 'Frida' }];
const textArea = document.querySelector('[data-id="textarea"]');
const nameWrap = document.querySelector('[data-id="names"]');

function inputListener() {
  let shouldListen = false;
  let index;
  return (e) => {
    const { value } = e.currentTarget;
    const currentValue = value[value.length - 1];
    if(shouldListen) {
      if(currentValue === ' ' || value.length - 1 < index) {
        shouldListen = false;
        return;
      }
      const str = (value.substr(index).match(/@(.+$)/)[1]).toLowerCase();
      const html = names
        .filter(({ name }) => name.toLowerCase().startsWith(str))
        .map(({ name }) => `<p>${name}</p>`)
        .join('');
        console.log(html)
     nameWrap.innerHTML = html;
    }
    if(currentValue === '@' && !shouldListen) {
      shouldListen = true;
      index = value.length - 1;
    }
  }

}
textArea.addEventListener('input', inputListener())
```

```html
<textarea data-id="textarea"></textarea>
<div data-id="names"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
let str = "@tr";

var users = [
  {
    name: "steve",
    id: 47 
  },
  {
    name: "james",
    id: 41
  },
  {
    name: "guy",
    id: 44 
  },
  {
    name: "troy",
    id: 32 
  }
];

const filteredUser = users.filter(user => user.name.includes(str.replace(/@/, "")));
console.log(filteredUser);
```

Comment: Sorry just another quick question how can I only check for the string after the @??

Comment: Yeah that's why i replace "@" with "".

Answer (score 0):

You may want `filter`

```js
const users = [
  {
    name: 'steve',
    id: 47 
  },
  {
    name: 'james',
    id: 41
  },
  {
    name: 'guy',
    id: 44 
  },
  {
    name: 'troy',
    id: 32 
  }, {
    name: 'stephon',
    id: 141
  }
];

const partialUserName = 'st';
const output = users.filter(user => user.name.startsWith(partialUserName)); 
// you can change to contains if that's what you want
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try search method

```
  const substr = 'tr';
   array.filter(( name ) => {
     return (
      name.toLowerCase()
      .search(substr.toLowerCase()) !== -1
       )
```

Hope this help